# How to send binary data from a Node.js socket.io server to a browser client?

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, socket.io, socket.io-1.0

I've been looking through the entire Socket.IO docs, but, even though they promise it is there, I can't find a simple, minimal example, of how one would send binary data between server/client.

How is it done?

Comment: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24124966/2600208) is an example of how to send image as a buffer from the server and render it on an HTML5 Canvas on a client.

Comment: @Viclib Did you got this done ? please share..!!!

Comment: Ah, I have, I've forgotten how at this point, sorry for not updating. But as far as I remember, all you have to do is to get a buffer from a Float32Array (or similar) (something like that: `myData = new Float32Array([1,2,3,4]).buffer;` and sending that via `socket.io`, ie, `socket.emit("foo",myData)`. It automatically treats it as binary data. Then, on the other end, you have to convert it back: `socket.on("foo",function(data){ data = new Float32Array(data); })`. I've written that by memory, though, but I remember there was an example on the blog post about the release of `socket.io` 1.0.

Answer (score 15):

It is in fact in the documentation. The current documentation for Socket.io says under [Socket.emit](http://socket.io/docs/server-api):

> [...] Emits an event to the socket identified by the string name. Any other
>   parameters can be included. All datastructures are supported, including Buffer [...]

So, if you can send a buffer, you can send binary data. All you have to do is to pack your data into a [Buffer](http://www.nodejs.org/api/buffer.html) object.

You may want to read [Socket.io Binary Support](http://socket.io/blog/introducing-socket-io-1-0/#binary) and [Sending and Receiving Binary](https://github.com/automattic/engine.io-client#sending-and-receiving-binary)

Comment: Ah, that is what I was missing, then. I was searching it wrong. It is automatic, then? If I send a Float32Array it will just go as binary, instead of being serialised to JSON?

Answer (score 3):

Starting from socket.io 1.0 it is possible to send binary data. http://socket.io/blog/introducing-socket-io-1-0/

How ever the way of sending and receiving binary data is not clear in the official documentation. The only documentation is:

```
var socket = new WebSocket('ws://localhost');
socket.binaryType = 'arraybuffer';
socket.send(new ArrayBuffer);
```

I suggest you to take a look at this answer, where you can find basic example with code implementation for server and client (javascript and java too):

[How to send binary data with socket.io?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34056705/how-to-send-binary-data-with-socket-io/)

The good part is that it also works on Android! (if you wish)

Cheers