# how to use socket.io 1.0 broadcast.emit webm blob data to client?

Tags: node.js, socket.io, webm

I want to broadcast blob to the client,this is my sever side code:

```
fs.readFile('./message.webm',function(err,data) {
    if (err) throw err;
    // here i broadcast the blob data
    socket.broadcast.emit('message', {
     video: data
    });
});
```

on the client side,I don't know how to set a video element to get the blob,i have see a image example,it so hard,i don't know how to do with video.

Comment: Do you mean to be using `fs.readFile()`?  And, why would you send video over a web socket?  Why not send a URL and let the client fetch the video from the URL?

Comment: use webRTC for your video broadcast, and socket.IO for signalling/control.

Comment: I have seen http://socket.io/blog/introducing-socket-io-1-0/,it support send blob data,so what i want is to send blob data.but in the client side,it seems complex,this is a example for image:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24107378/socket-io-began-to-support-binary-stream-from-1-0-is-there-a-complete-example-e

Comment: @haibo It's probably too long ago but.. have you been able to solve this riddle?